# I have some questions about Genymotion

Tags: google-play, genymotion

This might sound like a stupid question, but what is the current version of Genymotion? I just downloaded Genymotion this morning.

How do you download Google Play for Genymotion? I am emulating Android 4.4.0.

How do you get Clash of Clans on Genymotion?

I use a Mac, version 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

1. The current version is: **2.2.0**. You can check that out in Help menu
2. To install Google Play, you need to install some Google play services. Some of them are **GApps** , **PaGApps**.  You can google them out to know more.

   - You can get Gapps [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2397942). This version is for Virtual devices running 4.3 or above. There are different package available (micro, mini, full, stock). Read the description for all the details you need.
   - You can get paGApps [here](http://goo.im/devs/bevigilant/pa-gapps/). This also contains different packages. Read the full file name for more info

     You just need to drag and drop the downloaded **zip** file to
3. To your 3rd question, **Clash of Clans** is a 3d game. Though I haven't tried it on Genymotion emulator, the game might require some dependencies like **ARM Translation**. But, nothing can be learned without trying. So, try grabbing an APK of Clash of titans, drag and drop the apk to the emulator and check if it installs. If it does, try to play and enjoy.